# different number of results using google search api

Tags: php, api

I use google search API to extract the 80th first results. My problem is that each time I run the program, it gives me a different number of results (URLs).

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 42

```
    <?php

    $query='site:https://fr.wikipedia.org%20sport';
    $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&hl=fr&rsz=large&q=".$query;

    $body = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($body);

    $inF = fopen("fnm.txt","a"); 
    for($x=0;$x<count($json->responseData->results);$x++){

    echo "<b>Result ".($x+1)."</b>";
    echo "<br>URL: ";
    echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->url;
    fputs($inF,$json->responseData->results[$x]->url); fwrite($inF, "\r\n");
    echo "<br>VisibleURL: ";
    echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->visibleUrl;
    echo "<br>Title: ";
    echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->title;
    echo "<br>Content: ";
    echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->content;
    echo "<br><br>";
    }

    $j=0;
    for ($i= 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
    {
     $j=$j+8;
     echo $j;
     $query = 'site:https://fr.wikipedia.org%20sport';
      $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&hl=fr&rsz=large&start=$j&q=".$query;

     $body = file_get_contents($url);
     $json = json_decode($body);

    for($x=0;$x<count($json->responseData->results);$x++){

    echo "<b>Result ".($x+1)."</b>";
    echo "<br>URL: ";
    echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->url;
    fputs($inF,$json->responseData->results[$x]->url); fwrite($inF, "\r\n");
    echo "<br>VisibleURL: ";
    echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->visibleUrl;
    echo "<br>Title: ";
    echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->title;
    echo "<br>Content: ";
    echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->content;
    echo "<br><br>";
    }

}

fclose ($inF);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4353393/5214904.
In short: there is a limit without API key in 64 results

**Edited**:
See https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/#php-access
You need to send your/client IP in url and your site in REFERER field. You can do it with CURL.

Comment: My problem is that anytime i run the program i obtain a different number of  results (8, 16,...). .